# Trim all strings within a string array

Tags: c#, string

I'm having trouble trimming all the whitespaces(tab, etc.) for a given string. I've tried a number of recommended solutions, but have yet have any sort of luck.

for example

```
["7 ", "  +", "1",  "/"  "0""]
```

needs to return

```
["7","+","1","/","0"]
```

Another aspect to consider is that

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(exp, "(\\()|(\\))|(-)|(\\+)|(\\*)|(/)");
```

must also be used, and I'm working on a passed in string.

Comment: How about a simple loop? It's not the kind of task one needs a "recommended solution" for.

Comment: Can't you loop it with a simple `for` and `Trim` each?

Comment: Why must the regex shown be "considered"?

Answer (score 3):

You coud use Linq:

```
var a = new string[]{"7 ", "  +", "1",  "/", null, "0"};
var b = a.Select(x => x == null? null: x.Trim()).ToArray();
```

or do it in-place applying [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to every element.

---

> Another aspect to consider is that ...

This was not in the first edition of the question, and `Regex` is not considered in the answer.

Comment: LINQ is beautiful and all, but "within a string array" probably means he wants to mutate the array.

Comment: `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => ...`

Comment: @slugster Thanks! `"".Trim` is not a problem, but `null`s could be. I updated the answer.

Comment: Do you expect `null` in `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq too.

```
string text = "My text with white spaces...";
text = new string(text.ToList().Where(c => c != ' ').ToArray());
```